# Vue.js3 + .NET 6 API + Google login

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, google-oauth, .net-6.0

I have a vue.js SPA, that makes ajax calls to a .NET 6 API
I want users to login with their Google account, and authenticate to the API passing their google id/email
What's the best way to do this?

NOTE: I'm using vue.js via a CDN link in a static HTML/JS/CSS site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use the following method:

1. front(vue) call google auth2
2. get google token and post to backend(.net)
3. call google authenticator on backend to confirm success
4. You can Get Google UserID Name,and save it by JWT or Redis......and so on

Comment: Thanks Xiang.  For #1 (vue front) I'm using gapi, and get back an ID Token and Access Token.  I then pass the ID Token in header (as bearer) and have JwtBearer authentication setup for my controllers.
Is this what you mean for #2 and #3? Or do you pass the Access token, instead of ID Token and do it a different way?

Comment: I will pass the access token to the backend to confirm whether the verification is successful again. After getting the correct id token, write the id, username and other information into the JWT, and then use the JWT token issued by myself for verification(Add to Header)

Comment: Thanks so much Xiang... so, the Access Token is passed to an anonymous endpoint (e.g. /DoLogin), which calls Google to verify it and obtain username etc. and then .NET creates a new JWT which is passed back, stored on the client, and used in all subsequent endpoints (that have [Authorize])
Is this correct? I'm still trying to get my head around this, thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly, but I'm not sure if this is the most correct or the best way, but it has some security and is not complicated

Comment: Ahh I see.  Out of interest, how come you don't just pass the ID Token from client, and .NET just verifies the JWT?   I tried this and it works, but not sure if this is bad (i.e. allows for the ID Token to be tampered/spoofed)  Should the ID Token that I get back from gapi in vue not be trusted?

Comment: ID TOKEN must be verified. If the backend directly allows login or directly issues JWT after getting the Token, then why should I log in? Just pass fake information and it’s done, because the backend doesn’t need to verify

Let's say I use postman and post your backendAPI (/DoLogin)
{id_token: "easyLogin"}

However you will directly return the new JWT?

do you mean that

Comment: Yep, I thought that if I pass the ID TOKEN to my .net backend (in header), and then use .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options => ... then .net will verify the token, by verifying the signature in the JWT.  Is that not the case?

Comment: Your approach is to assume that you don't care about forged tokens. Like my example, if I pass any parameters, you will return JWT to me. What does this mean? Suppose I am John, and I pass ID_token="HaHaYou're stupid" username= "Cindy", you will identify it as Cindy and give him a legal Token

Comment: No I think you misunderstood my approach ... My API won't return a JWT - it only receives the JWT returned as ID TOKEN from Google (via gapi in the front end).  It receives the ID TOKEN, and validates the signature (to ensure it came from google), and if validated, trusts that the user is who they say they are

Comment: Sorry, because of the translation problem, I completely misunderstood what you meant. You are right. Use id_token to verify that you do not return, and then use access_token to make API request.

Comment: Thanks Xiang, access_token is only for making API requests to Google api's, and not my own API, is that right?